# i have tried the apt-get command but it gives the following info . Please help me

Tags: command-line

```
/home/user# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 atom : Depends: git but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Try - `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: And after that, run `sudo apt-get install git` and give us the output of `apt-cache policy atom git`

Answer (score -1):

Use command `sudo apt-get install git` and then try again

If that does not work. Open settings go to software and updates enable cannonical software and then exit out.

Use command `sudo apt-get install git` and then try again